# vim snipMate: expand snippet within a snippet

Tags: vim, snipmate

Using vim-snipmate I have the following problem:
If I try to expand a snippet within a snippet, snipmate takes me to the next placeholder of the current snippet instead of expanding the new snippet.

e.g.:
If you press `tab` in the following situation:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ifi<press tab here>
}
```

I would expect:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (<cursor position>) ;
}
```

but what I get is the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ifi
}<cursor position>
```

Is there a way to expand snippets within snippets or at least a way to suppress going to the next placeholder?

best regards

Answer (score 2):

The original [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=2540) did not support recursive snippet expansion. Apparently, the [fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) doesn't, neither. It wouldn't hurt to ask on the project's issue tracker for such support.

A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=2715). As far as I know, this one does support snippets within snippets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will definitely take a look at UltiSnips.
But besides another plugin, is it possible to stop the current "tab through the snippet"-process in snipMate?

Comment: `:unlet g:snipPos` will disrupt the current snippet expansion by clearing the plugin's context.

Answer (score 1):

[lh-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) and [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) support snippets within snippets, and even snippets that expand snippets (e.g. `switch` snippet relies on `case` snippet).

However, snippets syntax has nothing to do with the one from snipMate and consorts. And the placeholders system used is the old-school one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like that both of the plugins you posted don't support snippets for python/html snippets. Unfortunately, the latter is a criterion for excluding for me.

Comment: mu-template perfectly supports html/python/whatever. It's just that if the snippets don't exist yet, you'll have to write them (or to send me a draft of what is missing)